# lost windows in grub2 after windows update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

I updated Windows 8 to Windows 10 which caused my PC to start up in grub rescue. After fiddling around with testdisk I got Ubuntu 14.04 back but now I am stuck. I can't get Windows back into grub.

Below is the printout from testdisk:

```
TestDisk 6.14, Data Recovery Utility, July 2013

Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>

http://www.cgsecurity.org


Disk /dev/sda - 500 GB / 465 GiB - CHS 60801 255 63

     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors

  HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33    12 223 19     204800 [Reserveret til sys

   HPFS - NTFS             12 223 20 31727  92 45  509493248

   HPFS - NTFS          31727  92 46 31784 153 49     919552

   Linux                31784 186 19 60305 136 55  458186752

   Linux Swap           60305 136 56 60801  47 46    7962624
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a live CD or live USB?

In terminal, type: `sudo apt-get grub update`

or you can use grub-customizer: `sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`
and open `grub-customizer` to choose your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Boot Ubuntu and execute this command:

```
df -h
```

You will be shown a list of mounted partitions. Somewhere in there will be line which says `/` in the column "Mounted on". Look what this line says on the left. In my case it's `/dev/sda5`. Discard the number in the end for this, you only need what's before it. If it's any different, replace `/dev/sda` in the following command accordingly:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda && sudo update-grub
```